# Popup widget doesn't reopen in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

When  pressing a key the pop-up window opens by pressing the button, it closes, but when the key is pressed again, calling the pop-up window gives an error

> ***WidgetException('Cannot add %r, it already has a parent %r'***

```
import json
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


def read_json(file):
    FileJson = open(file)
    ObjJsom = json.load(FileJson)
    return ObjJsom


data = read_json('Task.json')

counter = 0
task_Headline = data['Tasks'][counter]['Headline']
label = Label(text="Label test for StackoverFlow")
ConBox = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
clButt = Button(text="Close", size_hint=(1, 0.1))
ConBox.add_widget(label)
ConBox.add_widget(clButt)


def btn(instance):
    show_popup(ConBox)


def show_popup(conten):
    show = conten
    popupWindow = Popup(title="Popup Window", content=show)
    clButt.bind(on_press=popupWindow.dismiss)
    popupWindow.open()


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        butt = Button(text='Press')
        butt.bind(on_press=btn)
        return butt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `Popup` with:

```
popupWindow = Popup(title="Popup Window", content=show)
```

it adds the `show` to the `Popup` instance. That set the `parent` property of `show`. When the `Popup` is dismissed an a new `Popup` is created with the line above, it fails because the `show` instance still thinks its parent is the old `Popup` (even though it has been dismissed). And any widget can only have one parent. The fix is to remove the `show` instance from the old `Popup` like this:

```
def show_popup(conten):
    # make sure the content has no parent
    if conten.parent is not None:
        conten.parent.remove_widget(conten)
    show = conten
    popupWindow = Popup(title="Popup Window", content=show)
    clButt.bind(on_press=popupWindow.dismiss)
    popupWindow.open()
```